# Generating multiple salts for already existing table

Tags: php, mysql, salt

So I'm tasked with taking over the creation of a survey webpage.  The security was non-existent before I took over.  There is a MySQL users table with passwords and I have added a salt column to generate a salt for every user. Importantly, this is not a live site and the passwords are all the same default password, so there is no worry if I have to change all the passwords.
My question is how can I generate an individual salt for all the users with a php script?  I tried with this...

```
$salt = dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647)).dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647));

$query_params = array(
    ':salt' => $salt
);

$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
```

and then updated the table with this...

```
$query = "UPDATE user
    SET salt = :salt
    WHERE salt = ''";
```

but it's not a loop I suppose and it gave everyone the same salt.
So I would like to know how to loop this through the table and populate the salt randomly for every user.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Don't. Use the build in `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` functions, you _should not roll your own password security_

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.random-bytes.php

Comment: What good is generating a salt if you're not also rehashing the password?

Comment: And yes, you'd need to `UPDATE ... LIMIT 1` row by row in a loop…

Comment: @deceze I will be hashing the password once I get individual salts

Comment: also @GrumpyCrouton that was my first thought but as it turns out the server is running PHP 5.4 and I'm not in a position to update it